# How to grant full site access to self?

Tags: permissions, access, access-denied, request-management

I am a new SharePoint site administrator, and the previous administrator has given me "Full Control" access over the site collection. Unfortunately, there are multiple folders within sub-sites that I am unable to access. Does anyone know how I can grant myself access to these folders within the sub-sites? I have tried requesting access once I come across a folder or sub-site that I do not have access to, but when I go to the Access Requests page and click "Approve" on my access request no action is completed, and the request remains. Subsequently I am still able to approve and decline requests from other users.

If anyone has some insight into what the issue may be that I am facing please let me know, or if there are resources you can point me towards I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: can some one add you in the Site collection administrator group?

Comment: In fact if you have only "Full Control" Permissions at site collection level, eg as "Site Owners", you cannot access on items with non-inherited permissions. The only way, as mentioned by Waqas, you have to find someone grants your account as "Site Collection Administrator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps:

**- Login to the site using Farm Account OR Admin Account.**

**- Go To Site Action >> Site Settings >> Site Collection Administrator**

**- Add your user name to Site Collection Administrator.**

**- By this you will have admin access for entire site collection.**